# Inequation complex number with fractions

Tags: complex-numbers

So my question is how can i solve this type of complex numbers inequality in general and this one in particular .

For which complex numbers is

$|z| ≥ \frac{15}{(|z| -2)}$?

I did tried many different things to do beginning with :

$|z| = \sqrt {a^2 + b^2}  $ because $z$ is a complex number , $z = a +bi$

$ \sqrt {a^2 + b^2} ≥ \frac{15}{(\sqrt {a^2 + b^2} -2)}$

${(\sqrt {a^2 + b^2} -2)} * \sqrt {a^2 + b^2} ≥ 15$

i think what i did until now is right, but i'm not sure how to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :**

Let $|z|=t>0$.

\begin{align}
t \ge \frac {15}{t-2} &\implies t -\frac{15}{t-2}\ge 0 \\
&\implies \frac{t(t-2)-15}{(t-2)}\ge 0\\
& \implies \frac{(t-5)(t+3)}{(t-2)}\ge 0\\
\end{align}

Comment: oh , i did not see that , thanks i got it .

Comment: Welcome @james. Glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply this out and solve by u-substitution.

$$|a^2+b^2|-2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\geq15$$
$$u = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$
$$|u^2|-2u\geq15$$

Because $u^2$ is always greater than or equal to zero, there is no need for the absolute value sign.

$$u^2-2u-15\geq0$$

This can be factored into:
 $$(u-5)(u+3)\geq0$$
$$u = 5, -3$$
Since $u$ is the modulus of a complex number, the answer would be any complex number with a modulus greater than $5$ (disregarding those less than $-3$).

Comment: $|z| \geq 5$ not just greater than. But this is not the only solution. An additional solution is $0 \leq |z| <2$. The reason you missed this out is because you made an implicit assumption when you multiplied the denominator out without worrying about the direction of the inequality.

Comment: @Deepak Learn something new every day! Thanks! I'll keep this up though just in case anyone can gain from your reply.

Comment: Glad you took it in the right way. To make things clearer, I typed up my own answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is permissible to multiply out both sides of an inequality by the denominator of rational expressions as long as *cases* are considered.

Let $|z| = x$, where $x$ is obviously non-negative. $x \neq 2$ otherwise the RHS would be undefined. Consider two cases:

Case $1$: $x > 2$. In which case, the sign of the inequality does not change when multiplying both sides by $x-2$:

$x(x-2) \geq 15$

$x^2 - 2x - 15 \geq 0$

$(x-5)(x+3) \geq 0$

leaving $x\geq5$ as the only permissible solution. The other ($x\leq-3$) is not permissible as $x$ is non-negative.

Case $2$: $x<2$. In which case, the sign of the inequality changes when multiplying both sides by $x-2$:

$x(x-2) \leq 15$

$x^2 - 2x - 15 \leq 0$

$(x-5)(x+3) \leq 0$

giving the solution $-3 \leq x \leq 5$. This has to be restricted based on the assumption of the case we're dealing with ($0\leq x<2$), so the solution becomes $0\leq x <2$).

Hence the final solution set is: $0\leq |z| <2$ *or* $|z| \geq 5$.